# Numpy - sum first row AND first column of matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Given the array `match`:

```
array([[ 0.03108485,  0.01272529,  0.00260469,  0.00035543],
       [ 0.0951713 ,  0.03896054,  0.00797469,  0.00108821],
       [ 0.14569118,  0.059642  ,  0.01220791,  0.00166586],
       [ 0.14868571,  0.06086788,  0.01245883,  0.0017001 ]])
```

Matrix rows represent 'home team' and matrix columns, 'away team'.

---

Draw probabilities is the `sum` of the array diagonal.

---

Also, I know there is a method for summing summing all elements below the diagonal (home wins) with:

```
np.sum(np.tril(match, -1))
```

---

and a method for summing all elements above the diagonal (away wins) with:

```
np.sum(np.triu(match, 1))
```

---

But I really need to sum all the values for when home team scores 0, in this first row:

```
[[ 0.03108485,  0.01272529,  0.00260469,  0.00035543],...]
```

And also all values for away team scores 0 goals:

```
[[ 0.03108485,
 [ 0.0951713 ,
 [ 0.14569118,
 [ 0.14868571,..]
```

---

Is there a method for summing the first row and the first column?

Comment: `match[0].sum()` and `match[:,0].sum()` ?

Comment: No because I ask for row sum as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get the sum you can different functions in numpy like :-

match[0].sum()

match[:,0].sum()

you can refer to this documentation for finding sum of array elements over the specified axis.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-sum-in-python/